# 5-methylhexa-1,3-diene reaction with HBr

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What will be the major product of the reaction?
I guess that rearrangement will take place and give 5-bromo-5-methylhex-2-ene as a product, but I'm completely not sure

Comment: Why do you think this will be the product?

Answer (score -2):

In this reaction if peroxide is not present then reaction follows markovnikov addition in which carbonation is formed as intermediate. By stability due to resonance and 2° carbonation
5-methylhexa-1-ene cation with C+ at 3 is formed. Hence 3-bromo-5-methylhexa-1-ene is formed as product.